# Python ArgumentParser - Error - Missing arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to run this code :

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()

ap.add_argument("-q", "--query", required=True, help="search query to search Bing Image API for")

ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=True, help="path to output directory of images")

args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

And I get this error :

> ```
> usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] -q QUERY -o OUTPUT
>
> ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required:
> -q/--query, -o/--output
> ```

I've tried to look into the ArgumentParser documentation ([here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method)), but couldn't find my answer. Could someone help me ?

Comment: Well, it tells you that you must provide arguments for your -q and -o. Hence, if you do not provide these arguments - the application fails

Comment: Can you add the command you used to run your code please?
It seems like you did not provide the arguments you set to required in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must launch the application providing the arguments indicated in the error message. In your code, both arguments are `required`. Hence, you must supply them to run the application.

Here is what it may be expecting

```
python ipykernel_launcher.py -q "<query>", -o "<dir>"
```

Note, the `<query>` and `<dir>` above are fillers. You must provide a query inline with applications definition of a query. The `-o` flag indicates a requirement to pass a directory. Hence, it could be as simple as `./output` or something between these lines.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Indeed, I needed to use it as a function and give it the arguments (instead of trying to run it directly).

Answer (score 0):

You set the `required` option to true:

```
ap.add_argument("-q", "--query", **required=True,** help="search query to search Bing Image API for")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", **required=True**, help="path to output directory of images")
```

(** added for visibility)
writing

```
ap.add_argument("-q", "--query", **required=False,** help="search query to search Bing Image API for")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", **required=False**, help="path to output directory of images")
```

instead, should fix the problem. Unless of course you want them to be required, then you have to call the script with the arguments.